# Understanding Eloquent One-to-many Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to understand Eloquent relationships but it seems I'm missing something in understanding it. I have:

- A `Meeting` produces many `Documents`.
- A specific `Document` can be produced for one `Meeting`.

Thus a one to many relationship.  I am trying to display the **'meeting_name'** in the `Document` details table but get this error:

> Trying to get property 'meeting_name' of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\yajra_contact_system\resources\views\documents\index.blade.php)

**Here is my code.**

Please please explain with code solution:

**app\Document.php File:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'document_name',
        'document_desc',
    ];

    public function meeting(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Meeting::class);
    }
}
```

**app\Meeting.php File:**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Meeting extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'document_id',
        'meeting_name',
        'meeting_desc',
        'room_no',
        'no_of_invitees',
        'comments'
    ];

    public function documents(){
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
    }
}
```

**app\Http\Controllers\DocumentsController.php File:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Document;
use App\Meeting;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DocumentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $documents =  Document::all();
        $meetings = Meeting::all();        

        return view('documents.index', compact('documents', 'meetings'));
    }
}
```

**resources\views\documents\index.blade.php File:**

```
@foreach($documents as $document)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$document->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$document->document_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$document->document_desc}}</td>
        <td>{{$document->meetings->meeting_name}}</td> <!-- ERROR IS HERE -->
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you post the result when you dd($document->meetings); most likely you are getting an array back. try $document->meetings->first()->meeting_name

Comment: When i try $document->meetings->first()->meeting_name : `Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Call to a member function first() on null (View: documents\index.blade.php`

Comment: I'm not too sure how to use dd() in the controller. a bit new to Laravel

Comment: that means that relationship you are trying to get is empty. just type this in your view after your @foreach, {{ dd($document->meetings) }} then refresh your browser

Comment: I get null for the value after I die and dump in the @foreach, {{ dd($document->meetings) }}

Comment: That means that the meetings is empty, could you post your documents model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215125/discussion-between-jelly-bean-and-kevind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your tables mixed up.

You have a single record per meeting yet you have a document_id in your meetings table which you would need to duplicate meeting record for each document.

> Remove the document_id from your meetings table
>
> Add a meeting_id to your documents table

remember to update your models fallible array else you wont get the new columns in the collection.

This should fix your problem as your relationships are correct.

Comment: Thanks alot Jelly Bean, I think your feedback showed me I had more problems with my database structure. My original code just worked after I took your advice on the db structure i.e swapping the FKs. After swapping the FKs, I also to change where my `belongsTo` and `hasMany` function went. So I am all goood.  FYI this video was most helpful also for this specific situation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Oxfi3DLdkI

Answer (score 2):

you have many problems in your code:

first: in order to use the relation ... you have to load it first ...

loading relation done by using with('relationName') method ...

in index:

```
$documents =  Document::with('meeting')->all();
```

second:

```
 <td>{{$document->meetings->meeting_name}}</td> <!-- ERROR IS HERE -->
```

the relation is named meeting without s .. not meetings ...

third:

it's pest practices to provide foreign key in relation:

in Meeting model

```
  public function documents(){
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class,'meeting_id');
    }
```

in Document model:

```
 public function meeting(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Meeting::class,'meeting_id');
    }
```

please make sure you have a column meeting_id in your documents table referenced as foreign key to id in meetings table

more details about loading relation in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading